# Decimal automatically rounds

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

In my SQL Server database in Visual Studio, I have a trigger `trgAfterUpdateAndInsertTeam`, which is executed when I insert a new row into my `Team` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdateAndInsertTeam]
ON Team
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @scoreperturn DECIMAL(6,3) = 0,
            @winlossratio DECIMAL(6,3) = 0,
            @idTeam INT = 0;

BEGIN
    /* Get data */
    SELECT
        @scoreperturn = [Score] / [Turns], 
        @winlossratio = [Wins] / [Losses], 
        @idTeam = [idTeam]
    FROM
        inserted

    /* Update data */
    UPDATE TEAM
    SET [ScorePerTurn] = ROUND(@scoreperturn, 3),
        [WinLossRatio] = ROUND(@winlossratio, 3)
    WHERE [idTeam] = @idTeam
END
```

The output in the table is a decimal number, the column is also a decimal. But it is rounded automatically. So when I should have an output like 3.421 it becomes 3.000 in the table. I tried with and without the `ROUND()` function but that makes no difference. What should I do?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ... @idTeam = [idTeam] FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account

Comment: Instead of a trigger, use a calculated column or calculate them in your `select` queries (maybe roll it into a view) for these values.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for your reaction. I get that my trigger is not suited for inserting multiple rows simultanously. However, because I don't need to that in my application that is not a problem. I don't have to take this into account now, but thanks for noticing. It can be useful for later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@marc_s is completely right, this trigger is going to cause you problems. if you `INSERT` 2 (or more) rows into your table, then only the team that filled the variables will be updated.

You would be much better off using a Calculated column and binning your trigger. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Team DROP COLUMN ScorePerTurn; --You'll need to drop the column first
ALTER TABLE Test ADD ScorePerTurn AS CONVERT(Decimal(6,3),CONVERT(Decimal(6,3),[Score]) / [Turns]); --Then add it again as a Computer Column.
--Then do the same for the other column
ALTER TABLE Team DROP COLUMN WinLossRatio;
ALTER TABLE Test ADD WinLossRatio AS CONVERT(Decimal(6,3),CONVERT(Decimal(6,3),[Wins]) / [Losses]);
```

And don't forget to `DROP` your trigger.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later. For now, my trigger is good. My problem was that some variables were INT when I declared them. So when calculating, SQL does not give me a decimal number, just 3.000 (for example).

However, this might be useful for later. I will remember it for sure! thanks! :)